# Why does an unassigned string not cause a compilation error in Python?

Tags: python

In my workings with python, I have sometimes found that I deleted a variable and just left the string inline in my code. I have noticed you can do this and there is no notification at all from the compiler or any runtime error when this occurs. Can someone tell me why this does not error out?

```
c = 1
"this causes no error or notification to the developer"
b = 2
```

This appears to work just like a docstring but there is no triple quotes, just a single set. I could not find any documentation on the subject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As in many languages, it is perfectly valid to have an expression that is not assigned to a variable.

```
3.14
"Boo!"
False
2 + 2
callable(func) and func()
```

Python will print the results of such expressions when they are executed interactively, but in a script, these values are simply discarded.

Such expressions may actually have side effects (such as the last one, which calls `func` if it's callable, and `func` can do anything at all) so it is not necessarily pointless to write such code.  In fact, a call to a function that does not return anything you need to keep around afterward is exactly the sort of thing you're objecting to, and is obviously useful.

Answer (score 1):

Because Pyhthon defines and allows that, aka known as [expression-statements](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#expression-statements)

I quote:

> Expression statements are used (mostly interactively) to compute and
>   write a value, or (usually) to call a procedure (a function that
>   returns no meaningful result; in Python, procedures return the value
>   None). Other uses of expression statements are allowed and
>   occasionally useful.